# How do I store orders to my cart and firesebase database

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing an ordering app in android studio.
I want to show the list of orders when the "cart" button is clicked

Here is what I have when "order" button is clicked

```
btnCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Database(getBaseContext()).addToCart(new Order(
                foodId,
                    currentFood.getName(),
                    numberButton.getNumber(),
                    currentFood.getPrice()
            ));
            Toast.makeText(FoodDetail.this, "Added To Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

my ***add to cart*** IS STILL EMPTY and this is what i only have

```
public void addToCart(Order order)
{
            order.getProductId(),
            order.getProductName(),
            order.getQuantity(),
            order.getPrice());

}
```

please help me :( thank you! :)

Comment: for firebase database you should be using FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() instead of Database(). you also need to set the ref path of your database. afterwhich you will use the setValue(order) method to save it in. see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Answer (score 0):

Here are a sample code to store data in the firebase key-value system with the key "message" and the value "Hello, World"

```
// Write a message to the database
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

here are some links that will help you

[Setup dependences to android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

[Get started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)

[Read and write data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely **NOT** how to store data in Firebase Database. You didn't create a FirebaseDatabase object to begin with. I'll assume you're using android studio to write this app (since that's one of the tags). To store data in Firebase database, follow the following steps:

- Connect your app to Firebase: Just go to the path below and follow the guidelines on completing the process.

  > **Tools > Firebase > Firebase Database**
- In your class, create a FirebaseDatabase object and set the value to `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()`. This reference points directly into your Firebase database and anything you store into this reference would be stored direectly. If you want to store data inside an inner folder inside this reference, use the `child()` method to nest.
- To store data, use the `setValue()` method of the FirebaseDatabase reference using the data to be stored as a parameter.

Example:

```
DatabaseReference someData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

someData.setValue("Little file");
```

You can also refer to the [Official Firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, im assuming you already include Firebase in your project.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("RefName");

myRef.setValue(new Order(
            foodId,
                currentFood.getName(),
                numberButton.getNumber(),
                currentFood.getPrice()
        ));
```

Comment: i doesnt add to cart :(